# Excel 2016 crashes when checkbox copied from one file to another

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2016 crashes when checkbox copied from one file to another after the update of excel 2016 (windows 10) from excel 2013 (Windows 7). Same macro works fine in excel 2013.

The property of Selection should be Object/OLEObjects after pasting, but it shows as Object/Range.

If I select the design mode in "two.xlsm" and run this code it is working fine, but we can't enable the design mode through code and run the code further, because enabling the design mode will stop the macro.

Also tried deleting the MSForms*exd files in temp/Excel and temp/VBE folders. not working.

```
Sub copy()

Dim Obj As Object
Dim toSheet As Worksheet

Set toSheet = Workbooks("two.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each Obj In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    Workbooks("one.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Workbooks("one.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array(Obj.Name)).Select
    Selection.copy
    toSheet.Activate
    toSheet.Paste

     Selection.ShapeRange.Name = Obj.Name

Next Obj
End Sub
```

Comment: If I add this line **'toSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Select'** after **'toSheet.Paste'**, the code is working. That line just selects the last pasted or created shape object.